# Windows 7 - Can't Disable Visual Styles on any Applications using: Properties > Compatibility

Tags: windows-7, visual-styles

I have installed the Ashtray Placebo theme

http://solmiler.deviantart.com/

I am attempting to disable the visual style for Adobe Fireworks because the controls are clashing with it's interface.

For some reason I am unable to disable via Properties -> Compatibility options on the .EXE. I have tried disabling on several other applications with the same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/getting-started-with-the-application-compatibility-toolkit.aspx) from Microsoft, create a new App Fix and select there to disable the Visual Themes.

Comment: unfortunately this seems to stop http://www.uxstyle.com/ from working, thus disabling non-preinstalled visual styles.

Comment: Got uxstyle working again.. Still disabling themes in Toolkit has no affect on Fireworks